# How to write a row_number() javascript UDTF on snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to get this user-defined table function to work but I am stuck.

I was just trying to make simple UDTF as part an effort to test some odd behavior I noticed with UDTFs, and I figured row_number() would be a good choice.  But it's not working, and I'm stuck.

Here's the UDTF:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION udtf_row_num()
    RETURNS TABLE(rn DOUBLE)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
VOLATILE
AS '
{
    initialize: function() {
        this.rownum = 0;
        this.inc = 1;
    },

    processRow: function (row, rowWriter, context) {
        this.rownum += this.inc;
        rowWriter.writeRow({RN:  this.rownum});
    },

    finalize: function (rowWriter, context) {/*...*/},
}
';
```

The problem is that it never increments!  The output is always 1.

Here's a query you can test with:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.customer_id,
    rn,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY a.customer_id ORDER BY a.id) AS rn_correct
FROM (
         SELECT
             seq4() AS id,
             seq4() % 3 AS customer_id
         FROM table(generator(rowcount => 20)) v
     ) a
JOIN table(udtf_row_num() OVER ( PARTITION BY a.customer_id
    ORDER BY a.id )) l
ORDER BY a.customer_id, a.id;
```

The columns `rn` and `rn_correct` should have the same values.

Instead, here's what I get:

```
ID  CUSTOMER_ID RN  RN_CORRECT
0   0   1   1
3   0   1   2
6   0   1   3
9   0   1   4
12  0   1   5
15  0   1   6
18  0   1   7
1   1   1   1
4   1   1   2
7   1   1   3
10  1   1   4
13  1   1   5
16  1   1   6
...
```

Comment: I think you need to do a lateral join, try changing `JOIN` to a `,` or `LATERAL`

Comment: I think `,` is the same as `JOIN`, and snowflake has no lateral join.

Comment: Try adding an input parameter -- even if it isn't utilized in the calculation -- and pass a column from the joined table into that param when you call the function.

Comment: Interesting.... yeah it works when it's a col from the table, but not when it's a constant.  I had tried before with constant `inc` parameter but not when a row from  joining table.